# Initilizer-list cannot convert to const MARGINS*

Tags: c++, margins

Today I jumped to Visual Studio (C++) 2013, I was using Codeblocks a lot of time but I realized that codeblocks starts to fail at compiling some codes like this:

```
//#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include "hMain.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <Uxtheme.h>

int Width = 800;
int Height = 600;

const MARGINS* Margin = { 0, 0, Width , Height };

char lWindowName[256] = "TEEEST";
HWND hWnd;

char tWindowName[256] = "TEEEST"; 
HWND tWnd;
RECT tSize;

MSG Message;

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            Render ();
            break;
        case WM_CREATE:
            DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, Margin);
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE) PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hSecInstance, LPSTR nCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{

    CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)SetWindowToTarget, 0, 0, 0);

    WNDCLASSEX wClass;
    wClass.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wClass.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    wClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wClass.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
    wClass.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)lWindowName;
    wClass.lpszMenuName = (LPCWSTR)lWindowName;
    wClass.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wClass))
        exit(1);

    tWnd = FindWindow(0, (LPCWSTR)tWindowName);
    if (tWnd)
    {
        GetWindowRect(tWnd, &tSize);
        Width = tSize.right - tSize.left;
        Height = tSize.bottom - tSize.top;
        hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED, (LPCWSTR)lWindowName, (LPCWSTR)lWindowName, WS_POPUP, 1, 1, Width, Height, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 1.0f, LWA_ALPHA);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0), LWA_COLORKEY);
        ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    }

    DirectXInit(hWnd);

    for (;;)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) break;
        if(PeekMessage(&Message, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            DispatchMessage(&Message);
            TranslateMessage(&Message);
        }
        Sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}

void SetWindowToTarget()
{
    while(true)
    {
        tWnd = FindWindow(0, (LPCWSTR)tWindowName);
        if (tWnd)
        {
            GetWindowRect(tWnd, &tSize);
            Width = tSize.right - tSize.left;
            Height = tSize.bottom - tSize.top;
            DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(tWnd, GWL_STYLE);
            if(dwStyle & WS_BORDER)
            {
                tSize.top += 23;
                Height -= 23;
            }
            MoveWindow(hWnd, tSize.left, tSize.top, Width, Height, true);
        }
        else
        {
            char* ErrorMsg[125];
            MessageBox(0, L"MAL", (LPCWSTR)L"Error - Cannot find the game!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            exit(1);
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

So, 2 question. First, how could I fix this compiler error: http://gyazo.com/6d7de9e0f3bad345dbbe7b9b80c90b8d And the second question. I realized that I must put an "L" and (LPCWSTR) before some chars*, this is 100% required? Is there any way to avoid that at least the (LPCWSTR)? Thanks for read.

Comment: Nevermind, it's a struct of 4 ints.

Comment: MARGINS is a windows structure which is used in the funcion DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea

Comment: check again the line of the DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea function because it uses Margin variable but I receive the same error, I was just  testing

Answer (score 1):

First,

```
 const MARGINS* Margin = { 0, 0, Width , Height };
```

is invalid. You probably want to create a new `MARGINS` object and initialize it with the given values, in which case you don't want `Margin` to be a pointer:

```
 const MARGINS Margin = { 0, 0, Width , Height };
```

Second, `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()` expects a `const MARGINS*`, which is a pointer to a `MARGINS` object. Just give it the address of `Margin`:

```
DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &Margin);
```

As to the wide character issues, I am assuming that you are compiling this with the "Unicode character set" in the project options. In this case, most strings in the Windows API will be pointers to wide characters (`wchar_t*`). However, you are allocating narrow character arrays (such as `lWindowName`) and casting them to a pointer to a `wchar_t`:

```
wClass.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)lWindowName;
```

This will give you all sorts of weird behaviours. Make sure your strings *really* are made of wide characters:

```
wchar_t lWindowName[256] = L"TEEEST";
```

This will allow you to drop most casts.

Comment: OMG I didn't realize that the function 2 argument was _In... Thanks you so much for both answers! :D